# apache2 working but not showing up in netstat?

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

When I check which ports/interfaces apache is listening on, I see that it is listening only for tcp6 connections:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1361/apache2
```

However, when I point my browser to 127.0.0.1 or to my interface address (192.168.75.10) I get the familiar 'It Works!' page, indicating that apache is listening for IPv4 connections too.

How is that?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152612/netstat-why-are-ipv4-daemons-listening-to-ports-listed-only-in-a-inet6